# Problema Método Post en Laravel 302 found

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema cuando hago un post en mi formulario de laravel. Cuando se envía el post, laravel redirecciona a la ruta del formulario sin ejecutar la funcion store del controlador y envia un status 302 found. Lei por ahí que puede ser por la autentificacion CSRF, pero el token de dicha autentificación si se lo estoy pasando en el formulario ( no se si también debe realizar una validación a nivel de controlador).

Gracias de antemano y estoy atento.

Este es el código:

**Routes/web,php**

```
Route::get('/formulario', function () {
    return view('formulario');
});


Route::post('/formulario/guardar', 'PdfController@store');
```

*** pdfController.php***

```
public function store(Request $request){


$this->validate( $request, [
    'fecha_pdf' => 'required|date|before:today'
    ]
);      


$arr_ip=geoip()->getLocation($request->ip());


        $DatosDeclarantes                       = new DatosDeclarantes;
        $DatosDeclarantes->rut                  = $request->rut; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->razon_social         = $request->razon_social; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->domicilio            = $request->domicilio; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->ciudad               = $request->ciudad; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->pais_constitucion    = $request>pais_constitucion; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->telefono             = $request->tlf; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->nro_iden_rp          = $request->nro_iden_rp; 
        $DatosDeclarantes->nombre_rep_legal     = $request->nombre_rep_legal; 

        if($request->tipo_entidad=='otra'){
            $DatosDeclarantes->tipo_entidad     = $request->tipo_entidad_text;  
        }else{
            $DatosDeclarantes->tipo_entidad     = $request->tipo_entidad;
        }

        $DatosDeclarantes->save();



        /*$ActDatos                             = new ActDatos;
        $ActDatos->reitera_informacion      = $request->reitera_informacion; 
        $ActDatos->nro_declaracion_jurada   = $request->nro_declaracion_jurada;
        $ActDatos->fecha                    = $request->fecha;
        $ActDatos->save();*/

        $PersonaDeclaracion                             = new PersonaDeclaracion;
        $PersonaDeclaracion->cni_identificacion         = $request->cni_identificacion; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->nombre         = $request->pd_nombres; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->apellido_paterno       = $request->apellido_paterno; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->apellido_materno       = $request->apellido_materno; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->lugar_origen       = $request->lugar_origen; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->relacion_pjd       = $request->relacion_pjd; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->nacionalidad       = $request->nacionalidad; 
        $PersonaDeclaracion->save();



    $TablePdf                                       = new TablePdf;
    $TablePdf->id_tipo_declaraciones        = $request->tipo_declaraciones;
    $TablePdf->id_datos_declarante      = $DatosDeclarantes->id; 
    //$TablePdf->id_act_datos               = $ActDatos->id; 
    $TablePdf->id_persona_declaracion   = $PersonaDeclaracion->id; 
    $TablePdf->ip                       = $arr_ip->ip; 
    $TablePdf->iso_code                     = $arr_ip->iso_code; 
    $TablePdf->country                  = $arr_ip->country; 
    $TablePdf->city                         = $arr_ip->city; 
    $TablePdf->state                        = $arr_ip->state; 
    $TablePdf->state_name               = $arr_ip->state_name; 
    $TablePdf->postal_code              = $arr_ip->postal_code; 
    $TablePdf->lat                      = $arr_ip->lat; 
    $TablePdf->lon                      = $arr_ip->lon; 
    $TablePdf->timezone                     = $arr_ip->timezone; 
    $TablePdf->fecha_pdf                    = $request->fecha_pdf; 

    $TablePdf->save();
    $id_pdf = $TablePdf->id;


 if(isset($request->bf_cni_id))
{
    $BeneficiariosFinales               = new BeneficiariosFinales;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->cni_id       = $request->bf_cni_id;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->nombre       = $request->bf_nombre;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->domicilio    = $request->bf_domicilio;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->ciudad       = $request->bf_ciudad;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->pais         = $request->bf_pais;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->porc_participacion       = $request->bf_porc_participacion;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->id_pdf       = $id_pdf;
    $BeneficiariosFinales->save();
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {

    if(isset($_POST["bf_cni_id$i"]))
    {
        $BeneficiariosFinales               = new BeneficiariosFinales;
        $BeneficiariosFinales->cni_id       = $_POST["bf_cni_id$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->nombre       = $_POST["bf_nombre$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->domicilio    = $_POST["bf_domicilio$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->ciudad       = $_POST["bf_ciudad$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->pais         = $_POST["bf_pais$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->porc_participacion       = $_POST["bf_porc_participacion$i"];
        $BeneficiariosFinales->id_pdf       = $id_pdf;
        $BeneficiariosFinales->save();

    }
}





 if(isset($request->bf_cni_id))
{
    $ControlEfectivo                = new ControlEfectivo;
    $ControlEfectivo->cni_id        = $request->ce_cni_id;
    $ControlEfectivo->nombre        = $request->ce_nombre;
    $ControlEfectivo->domicilio     = $request->ce_domicilio;
    $ControlEfectivo->ciudad        = $request->ce_ciudad;
    $ControlEfectivo->pais      = $request->ce_pais;
    $ControlEfectivo->porc_participacion        = $request->ce_porc_participacion;
    $ControlEfectivo->id_pdf        = $id_pdf;
    $ControlEfectivo->save();
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {

    if(isset($_POST["ce_cni_id$i"]))
    {
        $ControlEfectivo                = new ControlEfectivo;
        $ControlEfectivo->cni_id        = $_POST["ce_cni_id$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->nombre        = $_POST["ce_nombre$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->domicilio     = $_POST["ce_domicilio$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->ciudad        = $_POST["ce_ciudad$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->pais          = $_POST["ce_pais$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->porc_participacion        = $_POST["ce_porc_participacion$i"];
        $ControlEfectivo->id_pdf        = $id_pdf;
        $ControlEfectivo->save();

    }
}



        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Formulario guardado con exito!!');

        return  view('success', compact('id_pdf'));


    }
```

Comment: ¿a dónde envía ese 302?

Comment: a http://localhost:8000/formulario/guardar

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta general sería...

Para **saber si la ruta está funcionando** (el formulario se envía a la ruta esperada):

```
Route::post('/formulario/guardar', function(){
    dd('ruta OK');
});
```

Para **saber si el método del controlador recibe los datos del formulario** (si falla el CSRF no llegarán):

```
Route::post('/formulario/guardar', 'PdfController@store');

class PdfController extends Controller {
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd('PdfController / store()', $request->all());
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

#### ¿Cómo saber si falta el token CSRF en un formulario?

Puedes usar la opción "ver código fuente" del navegador en la página que contiene el formulario. Si buscas ***csrf***, debe aparecerte un *input de tipo hidden con el token CSRF*, y debe estar entre las etiquetas `<form></form>` del formulario que vas a enviar.

Para *poner el input con el token CSRF en un formulario en Blade* puedes usar:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví. El problema era el validate al principio de la función store. Lo que pasa es que habia un problema en el formulario que esta ingresando mal el campo 'fecha_pdf', lo que hacía que no validara el request de entrada y generara el redireccionamiento.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Y cuál era ese problema, pues tu respuesta no es clara